# Change resource's URL [CKAN]

Tags: ckan

All the resources that I upload from files end up with an URL that is not the URL that I can actually download the resource from.
That is, CKAN gives the URL `localhost:5000/dataset/and/so/on` however, the URL should be `localhost/dataset/and/so/on`. If I manually take out the port it works.
What should I do to change the URL that CKAN is assigning to the resources?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set `ckan.site_url` properly in your ini. See http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-site-url